# Why does my Ajax call have an empty POST?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

When I submit an Ajax request to save a form, I get an empty `request.POST` QueryDict. Hopefully I'm just overlooking something due to inexperience with Ajax. Here is the relevant code:

**Ajax**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        [...]
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            [...]
            $(".inline-save").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : '/webApp/saveForm/',
                        type : 'POST',
                        dataType : 'HTML',
                        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
                        success : function(info) {
                            $("#info-display").html(info);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

The form I intend to save is brought up with another Ajax call, thus the `ajaxComplete` usage. In my *urls.py* and *views.py*, I simply redirect to `save_view`, which just prints `request.POST` for now, which outputs `<QueryDict: {}>` - an empty QueryDict.

What am I missing? Even though there are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142832/django-ajax-modelform-submits-an-empty-form-to-request-post) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731880/django-ajax-unable-to-get-ajax-post-data-in-the-views-py) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384771/a-simple-ajax-request-post-empty), none that I've found have helped me so far.

Comment: You are not sending any data. No wonder

Comment: ... ... ... ... OH. /facepalm Well, at least I'm making this mistake as a newbie and not as someone with experience. :P

Comment: It happens! A part of the learning process

Comment: fyi jquery's [`.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is a bit cleaner way to write ajax POSTs.

Comment: `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'` is not required when using the jquery post method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `data : postData` to your `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/webApp/saveForm/',
    type : 'POST',
    data : postData,     // You need to add the data you want to send here
    dataType : 'HTML',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    success : function(info) {
        $("#info-display").html(info);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question very well but,try to see this document that explains Ajax with Jquery.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Try to it different. For example:

```
  $(".inline-save").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:PORT/webApp/saveForm",
                        dataType:'json',
                        data:$(".formName").serialize(),
                        success: function(msg) {
                            alert("Form supposedly saved",msg)
                            $("#info-display").html(info);
                        }
                  });
}
```

or just add there fields and see if it works for you:

```
data:$(".formName").serialize(),
```

or

```
data:{
   variableName : value,
   variableName2:value2
}
```

Hope it helps.